# What type of wood-boring insect cause this type of damage in a rafter?

Tags: wood, pest-control, insect

I recently discovered the following damages in a rafter. Location is California.

- What type of wood-boring insect cause this type of damage?
- What are some treatments to stop the cause?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That looks like damage done before the tree was cut, to me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be powder post beetles, or a similar small boring insect, since the holes appear to be fairly small.

A California resource suggests two alternate possibles as well - "false powderpost beetle" and "deathwatch beetle": https://ipm.ucanr.edu/PMG/PESTNOTES/pn7418.html

Comment: Are the beetles still in the rafter?